# What exactly happens to empty inline functions?

Tags: c++, inline

I'm writing code (using GCC 4.7.2), where I'm excessively logging stuff during the testing phase in countless positions of the code. These loggings should disappear on the release binary.

I'm doing the logging via a function just like `void log(std::string msg);`. As these function calls are many and distributed via the whole code in many files, I had the idea to make it an inline function and just give it an empty body for the release binary.

No my question is: what does the compiler do with it? Does the binary just contain the rest of the code without the function, does it contain a `nop`, or anything else? Could I eliminate the logging code from the binary completely by emptying the inline logging function?

I'm not only interested in an answer to solve the problem but I'm also curious about the compiler's behaviour itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want different code between debug and release, then that's an ideal use case for the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define log(ignored)
#endif
```

Then you're not leaving anything up to the compiler. You're guaranteed that only the debug version will have the extra calls. This is how `assert` works, too.

Note that this will also drop the parameter computation. For example, if you have `log(get_msg())` then the macro method will drop the call to `get_msg()` as well. This is probably desirable, but you need to be aware of it.

As for `inline`, that's entirely up to the compiler. The `inline` keyword itself is only a hint, it does not obligate the compiler to do anything. The compiler performs its own optimization calculations on whether or not to inline a particular function (that includes inlining functions not marked `inline`). That typically means a sufficiently high optimization level (i.e. -O3), and that the body of the inline function is visible in that particular compilation unit. For example, if the compiler only sees a declaration but the (maybe empty) function body is in a different .cpp file, then it cannot inline. But yes, if the compiler determines that there are no side effects, it is free to make the whole function disappear.

But again, there's no reason to depend on that when the preprocessor offers such a clean and widely used solution.

Comment: This actually has very different behavior from the empty inline function.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point about the parameter side effects getting dropped along with the no-op function. I submit that that's actually desirable in most situations like this.

Comment: About `inline` being a mere hint, this is perfectly correct. However, in this particular constellation, one can ignore that. GCC determines whether or not to inline a function based on whether the number of "virtual instructions" generated is below an a threshold (which you can influence with commandline options, the `inline` keyword, and attributes). In the case of an empty function, this number is zero, which is always below the threshold. Though using low/no optimization it will likely not optimize out the unused `string` temporary.

Comment: Does link-time optimization do inlining?

Comment: My main concern with depending on inlining is that you don't really know if it worked or not unless you look at the assembly or very verbose compiler messages. There are a number of things that can stop the inline, even if unintentionally.

Answer (score 4):

You might or might not be left with a trivially empty function (if for example, the function's address is used to make a pointer, then the function needs to exist).

But all inlined call sites will turn into nothing.  (And the compiler should choose to always inline direct calls to a function it can see is empty -- Adam's answer is correct about calls into other translation units making this difficult, but Whole Program Optimization can help even there)

Do note, however, that parameters to an inline function will still be evaluated.  They might also get inlined and mostly eliminated, but **side effects in parameters will occur**.  This is rather different from using a `#define` macro to eliminate the entire `log(...)` string from the source code.  The macro gets rid of the parameter computations, too.

Comment: This is an especially good point considering the `std::string` parameter in the `log` function in the question. The construction and destruction of the `string` object would not be easy for a compiler to optimise away, as the compiler cannot easily tell that it is free of side effects.

Comment: @hvd: It probably *isn't* free of side effects.  Allocation and deallocation are side effects.  The fact that the latter "undoes" the former is only true at a much higher level of abstraction.

Comment: I meant visible side effects. Compilers do already sometimes remove allocation and deallocation (`malloc` and `free`) if the allocated memory is not used, and "not used" is checked after other optimisations have been performed.