# Custom Compile Time Specifier For Debugging / Ignoring Functions

Tags: c++, debugging, preprocessor, compile-time

What are good ways to implement the following debugging features?
I would like to define an easy to use **function specifier** similar to inline that tells the compiler **when to completely ignore a function** based on enabled preprocessor flags.
Ideally, I want to declare functions like this:

```
DEBUG_FUNCTION_VERBOSE void saveMesh(const std::string &fileName, const Mesh &mesh, ...);
DEBUG_FUNCTION_INFO void logInfo(const std::string &message);
DEBUG_FUNCTION_CHECK void checkVertexAttributes(const Mesh &mesh);
DEBUG_FUNCTION_ERROR void logError(const std::string &messageOfDoom);
```

There is an **ordering** from less important and slow to critical and faster. The idea is that I set a preprocessor flag which determines which of these special debug functions are enabled. E.g., there might be a flag like DEBUG_LEVEL_CHECK which enables the latter two types of debug functions or another flag DEBUG_LEVEL_VERBOSE which enables all of them.
If a debug function type is disabled I essentially want the compiler to ignore all calls to that function, including the evaluation of its arguments (like assert in release mode).

One motivation for these features is **speeding up debugging**. I want to call such debug functions in my code and leave them there. **For controlling** what is output and checked, I rather want to use a **preprocessor flag** instead of inserting and removing calls to such functions manually.

Another motivation is to **avoid clumsy preprocessor guards** as much as possible when declaring and calling those functions.
Instead of calling a function like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL_CHECK
checkVertexAttributes(mesh);
#endif // DEBUG_LEVEL_CHECK
```

I simply want to call the function normally:

```
checkVertexAttributes(mesh);
```

Ideally, the implementation of this debugging scheme should have these properties:
First, there should be only one point in code per function where I have to declare its debug level (might be similar to adding a specifier like the inline keyword). Second, I want to define the debug level logic only once since that is always the same. Third, these debug functions have an arbitrary context (belong to some class, some namespace or ...) and I might want to add such functions later. That means which functions are debug functions should be independent of the implementation of the debug level logic itself. I don't want to bloat that logic with listing all the used debug functions at this place. Fourth, if a function is disabled, not only its execution itself but also the evaluation of its arguments should be skipped (like for assert). Lastly, I want to conveniently make calls of debug only functions dependent on that logic but in a transparent way as depicted above.

I saw this post:
[What exactly happens to empty inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657455/what-exactly-happens-to-empty-inline-functions)
But that rather looks like it will lead to redundant code in my case and I am not sure how you would apply that to overloaded functions that share the same name.

Comment: Is using normal `#ifdef` clauses not enough? As the answer you linked clearly states it guarantees that the line is completely ignored if the corresponding `#define` exists.

Comment: No, I was wondering about something easier and more transparent. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Your question was not updated. Anyway, what's easiest and most transparent is more of an opinion, thus not really suitable for SO. You can at least get the desired behaviour without any need to update code in multiple places by using my answer. Seems about as easy as it gets IMO. Sure, the function signature will not show that the function is a debug-only thing, but you could add a comment there. Is that why you are looking for an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
inline void saveMesh(...) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    ...
    #else
    return;
 }
```

If `DEBUG` is not defined, any calls to that function won't do anything, and the compiler might completely optimise it out. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I am not sure if that is such a good idea. One issue is simply that the debug functions might be quite long. In such a case I would not like to have such a long debug function inline and in a header file. That in turn means that I always need to have two versions of them. An empty inline function if it is deactivated and a normal debug version if the corresponding preprocessor flag is enabled. Additionally, the same implementation of this scheme would reoccur for each function with the same debug level. I would like to avoid this redundancy and am looking for a smarter way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the compiler swallow any function calls with a variadic macro.

```
void test(int, int) {}
void test(int) {}

#define test(...)

int main()
{
    test(78, 12);
    test(12);
    test(swallows literally anything);
}
```

As for the levels, you can put some `#ifdef`s together and make a simple working system for it.

```
#ifdef DEBUG_FUNCTION_VERBOSE
#define DEBUG_FUNCTION_INFO
#else
#define saveMesh(...)
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG_FUNCTION_INFO
#define DEBUG_FUNCTION_CHECK
#else
#define logInfo(...)
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG_FUNCTION_CHECK
#define DEBUG_FUNCTION_ERROR
#else
#define checkVertexAttributes(...)
#endif

#ifndef DEBUG_FUNCTION_ERROR
#define logError(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Notice that behavior of remaining program might change for calls like `test(function_with_side_effect())` (same as for `assert`).

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean change as in the side effect will not happen?

Comment: Yeah, happen with `assert` too, so code such as `assert(db.open() == success)` is wrong.

Comment: Using variadic macros to make compilers ignore functions is nice. Though this solution seems to me like assuming that I already know all my debug functions beforehand so that I can gather their variadic macros in a code block like the one you suggested. But what if I want to add such debug functions without needing to put them in one such place (to avoid including the header often and recompiling quite some source files that depend on it). The debug level logic is not changing though and it would be nice to encapsulate that in a single place and put it in a general debugging header.

Comment: @Samir Well, looking at your updated specific requirements, you are basically describing a language feature that just doesn't exist. There are no custom function specifiers in c++, and there is none that does what you want. Which of the requirements to compromise on is probably easier answered by yourself.

Comment: The solution does not literally need to be function specifier. I just used that as an example analogy to make clearer what the problem is, what I would like to have and how and in which context I would like to use the solution. The whole thing might be implemented using some macro or template scheme. I still wonder how.

Answer (score 0):

I compromised some of the requirements and came up with this:

```
#include <functional>

enum class Debug
{
    Verbose = 0,
    Info = 1,
    Check = 2,
    Error = 3
};

#define DebugLevelApp Debug::Verbose


template <Debug functionLevel, typename Function, typename... Args>
inline void debugCall(Function&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (DebugLevelApp <= functionLevel)
    {
        auto function = std::bind(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        function();
    }
}

int main()
{
    debugCall<Debug::Verbose>(debug1, sideEffect());
    debugCall<Debug::Verbose>(debug2, sideEffect(), sideEffect());
    debugCall<Debug::Info>(debug2, sideEffect(), sideEffect());
    return 0;
}
```

The disadvantage here is that all the arguments are evaluated, even if the respective function is not called. This pretty much looks like unwanted surprising behavior.

So I changed the implementation of the debugging scheme to this:

```
enum class Debug
{
    Verbose = 0,
    Info = 1,
    Check = 2,
    Error = 3
};

#ifndef DEBUG_LEVEL_APP
    #define DEBUG_LEVEL_APP Debug::Info
#endif // DEBUG_LEVEL_APP

#define DEBUG_CALL(CALL_DEBUG_LEVEL) if constexpr (APP_DEBUG_LEVEL <= CALL_DEBUG_LEVEL)
```

If I want to have debug function calls that I can easily exclude using the preprocessor flag DEBUG_LEVEL_APP I mark such calls in this way:

```
DEBUG_CALL(Debug::Verbose)
debug2(sideEffect(), sideEffect());
DEBUG_CALL(Debug::Info)
debug2(sideEffect(), sideEffect());
DEBUG_CALL(Debug::Info)
debug1(sideEffect());
```

Here are no side effects for functions that are not called. This implementation is more explicit than what I wanted initially but that might be better in the end anyway. I'm still open for suggestions for how to improve on this scheme though.